# Fill cell within a dataframe according to another dataframe [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes such as

**Tab1 :**

```
ORFs_values      Groups       SP1  SP2   SP3
SP_ORF1          Group1       1    1     0
SP_ORF1          Group2       0    0     0
SP_ORF1          Group3       0    1     0
SP_ORF1          Group4       1    1     1
SP_ORF1          Group5       1    1     1
```

and another:

**Tab2**

```
Groups         SP_names   SP_names2
Group1         SP1        SP1_A
Group1         SP2        SP2_A
Group3         SP2        SP2_BL
Group4         SP1        SP1_BI
Group4         SP2        SP2_OP
Group4         SP3        SP3_I
Group5         SP3        SP3_0 
Group5         SP3        SP3_P
Group5         SP3        SP3_K
```

And I would like to replace within the **Tab1** all cells with 1, and with their corresponding `SP_names2` for each matching `Groups` and `SP_names`.

For instance, in the first row of **Tab1**, the `SP_names2` value for `SP1` in `Group1` is `SP1_A`, so I replace 1 by `SP1_A` and so on...

I should then get the following output:

**New_tab1:**

```
ORFs_values      Groups       SP1      SP2       SP3
SP_ORF1          Group1       SP1_A    SP2_A     0
SP_ORF1          Group2       0         0        0
SP_ORF1          Group3       0         SP2_BL   0
SP_ORF1          Group4       SP1_BI    SP2_OP   SP3_I
SP_ORF1          Group5       0         0        SP3_0|SP3_P|SP3_K
```

Here are the two df in dict format if it can help:

**Tab1**

```
{'ORFs_values': {0: 'SP_ORF1', 1: 'SP_ORF1', 2: 'SP_ORF1', 3: 'SP_ORF1'}, 'Groups': {0: 'Group1', 1: 'Group2', 2: 'Group3', 3: 'Group4'}, 'SP1': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1}, 'SP2': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1}, 'SP3': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1}}
```

**Tab2**

```
{'Groups': {0: 'Group1', 1: 'Group1', 2: 'Group3', 3: 'Group4', 4: 'Group4', 5: 'Group4', 6: 'Group5', 7: 'Group5', 8: 'Group5'}, 'SP_names': {0: 'SP1', 1: 'SP2', 2: 'SP2', 3: 'SP1', 4: 'SP2', 5: 'SP3', 6: 'SP3', 7: 'SP3', 8: 'SP3'}, 'SP_names2': {0: 'SP1_A', 1: 'SP2_A', 2: 'SP2_BL', 3: 'SP1_BI', 4: 'SP2_OP', 5: 'SP3_I', 6: 'SP3_0 ', 7: 'SP3_P', 8: 'SP3_K '}}
```

**#Edit, what If I have duplicates as in the `Group5` example, is it possible to add all the duplicates `SP_names2` separated by a pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `mask()`

`df` is Tab1 and `df2` is Tab2

```
df = df.set_index('Groups')
(df.mask(df.eq(1),
         df2.set_index(['Groups','SP_names'])['SP_names2'].unstack())
 .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   Groups ORFs_values     SP1     SP2    SP3
0  Group1     SP_ORF1   SP1_A   SP2_A      0
1  Group2     SP_ORF1       0       0      0
2  Group3     SP_ORF1       0  SP2_BL      0
3  Group4     SP_ORF1  SP1_BI  SP2_OP  SP3_I
```

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your help, by using your code I found that sometime in my dataset I can have multiple duplicates of  ```SP_names```  in the same group with different ```SP_names2```, do you think it is possible to add them with a pipe as separator ?